# Issues with running app from MainWindow nib?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I had the entire app (it consists of one view) set up and ran from a View in the ViewController object of the MainWindow nib, INSTEAD of actually having the view ran from the actual ViewController nib.

[image]

The app runs flawlessly, however I have two warnings. I learned that these warnings are caused by me running everything from the MainWindow nib rather than a ViewController.

Are there any issues with running an app from the MainWindow rather than an actual ViewController? The app is text based and involves constantly updating UILabels. You can find it here if you'd like to take a look at what I'm talking about.

Right now having it set up this way causes no issues... however I am planning on expanding the app. I tried copy and pasting my Scroll View to the actual view controller nib, but when I did I just had a grey screen. Can I leave the app as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But what is there in your MainWindow.xib file? If you just want to have window object, go to your applicationDidFinishLaunching method and create a window object.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

      UIWindow *appWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      self.window = appWindow;
      [appWindow release];
 }
```

**Or you could have select the option Window-Based application while creating a new project.**

Comment: I rebuilt the app based around the Window-Based application template. Thanks for the suggestion.